# How do I set different properties for different instances of ListView in a Kivy App?

Tags: android, python, listview, kivy, kivy-language

I want my Kivy app to have multiple ListView instances. I'm stuck when it comes to assigning different properties, especially callbacks. The following code illustrates my problem:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
<smRoot>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
<ListItemButton>:
    on_press: app.callback1(self)
    height: dp(25)
    size_hint: (1,.1)
<Screen1>:
    name:'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen1'
            size_hint_y: .1
        ListView:
            id:lstScreen1    
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[{'text':'item1'},{'text':'item2'},{'text':'item3'}],
                args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text']},
                cls=ListItemButton,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=False)
        Button:
            text: 'Switch Screen'
            size_hint_y: .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'
<ListItemButton>:
    on_press: app.callback2(self)
    height: dp(25)
    size_hint: (1,.1)            
<Screen2>:
    name:'screen2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen2'
            size_hint_y: .1
        ListView:
            id:lstScreen2    
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[{'text':'item1'},{'text':'item2'},{'text':'item3'}],
                args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text']},
                cls=ListItemButton,
                selection_mode='single', 
                allow_empty_selection=False)
        Button:
            text: 'Switch Screen'
            size_hint_y: .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
''')

class smRoot(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    MyButt = ListItemButton
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        smroot = smRoot()
        return smroot

    def callback1(self, btn_instance):
        index = btn_instance.index
        print 'From Screen 1: ' + str(index)

    def callback2(self, btn_instance):
        index = btn_instance.index
        print 'From Screen 2: ' + str(index)

myApp().run()
```

Here, I want each of the ListView instances on Screens 1 and 2 to have separate callbacks. But when I click on either screen, the output is the same, like so:

```
From Screen 2: 0
From Screen 1: 0
```

Ideally, I was hoping to implement something like a  [Dynamic Class](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes). But when I tried something like this:

```
<MyButt@ListItemButton>:
    #on_press: app.callback1(self)
    height: dp(25)
    size_hint: (1,.1)
<Screen1>:
    name:'screen1'
    MyButt:
        on_press: app.callback1(self)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen1'
            size_hint_y: .1
        ListView:
            id:lstScreen1    
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[{'text':'item1'},{'text':'item2'},{'text':'item3'}],
                args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text']},
                cls=MyButt,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=False)
```

I get a `NameError: name 'MyButt' is not defined` error. As far as I can tell, I've adhered to the same syntax in the documentation example linked above, so I'm confused.

I haven't tried creating a custom class in Python, but I would rather keep the UI elements separate in the .kv code (If I'm not mistaken, isn't that the basic idea behind kv?).

Any help/pointers/suggestions in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a widget class from the python side (after ":") in kv without importing it, but since `MyButt` is not defined in any module, being a dynamic class (defined in pure kv) you can use `Factory` to use it.

first, import Factory at the top of your kv file.

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

then change

```
    ListView:
        id:lstScreen1    
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[{'text':'item1'},{'text':'item2'},{'text':'item3'}],
            args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text']},
            cls=MyButt,
```

to

```
    ListView:
        id:lstScreen1    
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[{'text':'item1'},{'text':'item2'},{'text':'item3'}],
            args_converter=lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text']},
            cls=Factory.MyButt,
```

Comment: Thank you! A quick follow-up question: does this mean that this situation would have been avoided had all the stuff in the paranthesis, i.e. `ListAdapter(data=...)`been instead declared using kv rather than Python...? And in general, would that be recommended practice?

Comment: If it was possible to do the same in kv, yes, it would allow to avoid using Factory, and imports, etc… But kivy doesn't allow this here, because you have to assign that to a property, so your code is to the "right-hand" side of the assignation, in kvlang, this right-side (right of the ":") is evaluated by python directly, so there is no better solution to that particular problem. In short KVlang is best at declaring widgets, less at munapulating other classes, like ListAdapter.